# Timing actions in js (frame per second)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm doing a little mini-game and I need to do some animations (like frames per second), so far I manage to do this on my own:

```
var loadCount = 0;
var ticks = 15;


function loadingLoop() {
    loadCount++;
}

switch (loadCount) {
    case 1:
        $("#img").attr("src", "src/images/cenario/img004.png");
        break;
    case 2:
        $("#img").attr("src", "src/images/cenario/img005.png");
        break;
    case 3:
        $("#img").attr("src", "src/images/cenario/img006.png");
        break;
    // etc.... //
}

setInterval(function(){ 
    if (loadCount >= 6 && loadCount <= ticks){
        loadingLoop();
        if (loadCount === ticks) {
            clearInterval();
        }
        console.log(loadCount);
    }
}, 500);
```

So I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Try asking more specific question

Comment: Couple of comments: preload the images and swap them out using .show / .hide - if they move, move the wrapper div rather than the img.  `clearInterval()` does nothing without an interval to clear

Comment: If you intend declare some variables, a switch statement that does nothing useful and call an anonymous function every 500 milli seconds, that's the best way to do it. This code makes no sense for any other case. IMHO

Comment: @Aleksandar this code is for changing the background, so a set a loadCount and by using a Switch, every time it gets to a specific number on the loadCount the background changes. I tried doing that with a for each loop but it didn't work. 
What I want to know is if here is a better way to make it, 'cause it's working so far, I just want to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Because the numbering of your images is so clearly linked to the loadCount you could cut down the lines of code needed. Instead of having to spell out each instance in a switch you could simply have something like this:

```
  $("#img").attr("src", "src/images/cenario/img" + (loadCount+3).toString().padStart(3, '0') + ".png");
```

`padStart` takes a string which represents a number and pads it at the start with a character, in this case we've asked for 0s to be put at the front. The 3 indicates that we want 3 digits.

The other thing I noticed in your timing function is that you do not save your setInterval, but you try to clear it. Depending on what you are trying to do you probably need something like:

```
let interval = setInterval(function(){ 
    if (loadCount >= 6 && loadCount <= ticks){
        loadingLoop();
        if (loadCount === ticks) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        console.log(loadCount);
    }
```

}, 500);

Comment: The tip about the img is really nice, thanks. About the interval, I made so for every time an interval happens it adds 1 to the loadCount. so the loadCount is basically a way to use the interval as a timer. But the problem is that it keeps going forever so the:
``` if (loadCount === ticks) { clearInterval(interval); }´´´
is just a way that I found to control how many times the interval will loop. (without it the interval just keep looping forever and adding more ticks to the loadCount)

Comment: Hi, yes it was just that you were calling clearInterval without giving it an interval to clear, hence the bit about remembering interval then clearing it. Otherwise it goes on forever.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that